# Can not access APIs | Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, forge

I have three APIs. When i do `php artisan route:list` APIS are available there.
[image]

But only the third api is accessable from postman. can not access first two. they returns 404
[image]

My application is deployed in digital ocean using Nginx!

Comment: How are you attempting to access them?

Comment: i am trying to post some data using postman. But it says 404 for the first two api

Comment: Is that `chnagePassword` spelling correct in your route name? Can you show us the controller functions, and the Postman config you're using?

Comment: yes! btw solved it. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/catch-all` was responsible for denying the request.
I had to configured it correctly!